# PHPMailer Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Message body empty

Tags: php, phpmailer

So this is my code, it seems like it doesn't catch my "content" input field which is not empty btw, however I get this error

Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Message body empty

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'intrepid.servers.prgn.misp.co.uk';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'secret@secret.co';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->addAddress('myemailforreceivingemails@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']);
}
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->Body    = $_POST["content"];

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

This is from my index.php file

```
function sendContact() {
        var valid;
        valid = validateContact();
        if(valid) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "contact_mail.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#mail-status").html(data);
                },
                error: function(){}

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: check $_POST["content"] for blank value and send mail only when $_POST["content"]; is not blank

Comment: I'll do that right now

Comment: what is new FormData? are you using any additional plugin? you can pass add data simply by serialize method.